# Data Validation Between 2 adjacent cells for all rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

How would I create a data validation between 2 adjacent cells for all rows. For example cell B1 shows an error when the user tries to enter a value greater than the value in cell A1. I know how to do data validation for each cell, but how would I make it work for each row without manually adding validation between cells A2 and B2, A3 and B3 etc.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select `Column B`
2. In `Data Validation -> Custom`, type in the formula for the first row (i.e. `=B1<A1`)

And you're done!

Excel will automatically adjust the formula for each row